# How to create e-wallet in laravel website

Tags: laravel, payu

I am developing a website in laravel I want to apply a e-wallet system on my website(Like Paytm).

This is first time I am doing this, I read on different places, saw methods using java and also read that I can sign-up for existing Wallets like PayTM, Payu Money, etc and integrate the same in the store. 
But how to do it?

I used: https://github.com/tzsk/payu to add payu on my website.

Can you please tell me how can I make such a wallet? I have a wallet named table in databse when I added payu with one of the pages, I think it might bs used?

I made this wallet link, which will link user to different page where he can add money to his wallet as in here : https://paytm.com/paytmwallet

But, how can I add the payu feature of adding money to the wallet there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to register as a merchant for a payment gateway on payemnt gatway providers like [traknpay](https://www.traknpay.com) or [payu](https://www.payubiz.in/) and if your business is approved they will provide you with all details about integrating it in your website using there apis.

Comment: Checkout `https://www.bidwarriors.com/index.php` are you looking for something like this (register and try), also let me know your website.

Comment: Okay I'll check it and currently I'm working on my local server. I'll let you know when I'll host it on another server

Comment: I wanted to built something similar in laravel REST Api which is to be operated in New Zealand.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My organization provide e-wallet APIs, if you need more details drop an email at care@traknpay.com, do mention stackoverflow in subject line.